# Problemas al hacer una consulta SQL con el uso del UNION

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente problema al intentar hacer esta consulta `SQL` en `MySQL`

```
SELECT *  
 FROM Like__post 
 WHERE id__post_ = 2 
UNION 
SELECT * 
 FROM Post 
 WHERE id__post = 2` me genera el siguiente error `
SELECT * 
 FROM Like__post 
 WHERE id__post_ = 2 
UNION 
SELECT *  
 FROM Post 
 WHERE id__post = 2 LIMIT 0, 25
```

> MySQL said: Documentation
>   #1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`

La verdad no se porque se causa este error

Comment: ¿Qué estás tratando de lograr? El error es bien claro: estás tratando de unir columnas de 2 tablas diferentes que, o no corresponden en la cantidad de columnas, o las tipos de las columnas no corresponden. Para hacer un `union`, las columnas de las 2 consultas deben corresponder para que se pueda generar un resultado unificado.

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el esquema de las tablas `Like__post` y `Post` con, por ejemplo, `SHOW CREATE TABLE Like__post` (y luego la otra)? Además, ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? Si es obtener datos relacionados de ambas tablas no debes usar `UNION`, si no algún `JOIN`. Si nos dices los campos de las tablas y qué quieres obtener con la consulta, podremos ayudarte mejor que simplemente decirte un "las tablas no tienen el mismo número de campos".

Answer (score 1):

El operador `UNION` se utiliza para combinar el conjunto de resultados de dos o más instrucciones `SELECT`.

Y para poder usarlo, se deben cumplir estas tres reglas

- Cada instrucción SELECT dentro de la unión debe tener el mismo número
  de columnas
- Las columnas también deben tener tipos de datos similares
- Las columnas de cada instrucción SELECT también deben estar en el
  mismo orden

Answer (score -1):

los SELECT que componen el UNION tienen que tener la misma cantidad de columnas y mismos nombres.
compara la estructura de Like__post y post para ver si ahi no esta el problema.

Comment: No necesitan tener los mismos nombres.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, con que sean iguales la estructura de datos(String, tamaño del campo, etc...) sería suficiente

Comment: No es obligatorio el mismo nombre de la columna